# Debug Renderer Process

Tags: remote-debugging, electron.net

I have just started to use Electron.NET / electronize and it works well.

But how can I debug the renderer process via Visual Studio Code?

In my plain electron application I can do it by adding `--remote-debugging-port=9222` to the cli args.

How can I do it with Electron.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I got it :-) I figured out that cli arguments for Electron must be passed with the "/args" argument.

The solution is to run `electronize start /watch /args --remote-debugging-port=9223`